# location.href is decoding the URL

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function:

```
function QuoteBeGone(url)
{
    location.href = url;
}
```

The URL that is passed is encoded, for example `http://www.target.com/page.asp?name%3DJohn%27s%2BProject`, but when the new page loads, the URL is unencoded - `http://www.target.com/page.asp?name=John's+Project`.

The apostrophe is messing up the page, so I would like to keep it encoded in the URL, but it doesn't seem to stay that way. I assume the location.href function is interpreting the URL before passing it along.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why the apostrophe is messing up the page?

Comment: I tried the encodeURI already, but the string is already encoded properly to begin with so that doesn't work.

Comment: you sure about http://www.target.com/name=John%27s&20Project being the right url passed? the '&' looks a bit fishy

Comment: Sorry, just fixed that - was supposed to be %20, not &20.

Comment: It's a browser issue, each browser has its own way of dealing with url encoded addresses.

Comment: This is a result of the browser parsing and normalizing the URL before fetching the page.  It is entirely outside your control.  If you have a problem with embedded apostrophes, properly escape your inputs.

Comment: Thanks guys, I may have to locate where it reads the data from the database, and escape it before it gets to the page, as Mike suggested.  The big issue is that this is an old classic ASP app with dozens of include files, so there's no such thing as a quick fix!

Comment: @raina77ow The problem with it is that the parameter is read and written into a ton of javascript code that is enclosed with single quotes.  So an extra single quote is not expected in the middle.  I have been fixing that, but it's a really big job and I was hoping for a simpler solution.  Simply changing the apostrophe to %27 in the URL fixes it, so I was hoping I could force it somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the place where you are creating the URL that you are passing to the function use `encodeURIComponent()` on the value for `name`

e.g.

```
var john = "John's Project";
QuoteBeGone('http://www.target.com/page.asp?name='+encodeURIComponent(john));
```

If you want it to still be encoded after a decode due to navigating to that URL, then you have to double encode:

```
QuoteBeGone('http://www.target.com/page.asp?name='+encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(john)));
```

Comment: Thanks Alex.  That may work, and I had considered it, it just wouldn't be an easy solution to implement.  The url parameter is created elsewhere in very messy code.  It might be worth the attempt though.

Comment: @PhillipXT Definitely worth the attempt. The whole reason the URL is breaking in your case is because the query parameter values contain special characters that aren't allowed in URLs.

Comment: That seems to work, but now I will need to update the pages to decode the text of that parameter.  It shows up on the screen as John's+Project, so it needs some further decoding.  But the page isn't breaking, which is the important part!